# Pointfree version worsens the performance

Tags: performance, haskell, pointfree

Well, it turns out that I got this function defined in my program code:

```
st_zipOp :: (a -> a -> a) -> Stream a -> Stream a -> Stream a
st_zipOp f xs ys = St.foldr (\x r -> st_map (f x) r) xs ys
```

It does what it seems to do. It zips (applying the operator several times, yes) two elements of type `Stream a`, which is a list-like type, using an inner operator of the type `a`. The definition is pretty straightforward.

Once I had defined the function this way, I tried this other version:

```
st_zipOp :: (a -> a -> a) -> Stream a -> Stream a -> Stream a
st_zipOp = St.foldr . (st_map .)
```

As far as I know, this is *exactly* the same definition as above. It is just a point-free version of the previous definition.

However, I wanted to check if there was any performance change, and I found that, indeed, the point-free version made the program run slightly worse (both in memory and time).

Why is this happening? If it is necessary, I can write a test program that reproduces this behavior.

I am compiling with `-O2` if that makes a difference.

### Simple test case

I wrote the following code, trying to reproduce the behavior explained above. I used lists this time, and the change in the performance was less noticeable, but still existent. This is the code:

```
opEvery :: (a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
opEvery f xs ys = foldr (\x r -> map (f x) r) xs ys

opEvery' :: (a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
opEvery' = foldr . (map .)

main :: IO ()
main = print $ sum $ opEvery (+) [1..n] [1..n]
 where
  n :: Integer
  n = 5000
```

The profiling results using `opEvery` (explicit arguments version):

```
total time  =        2.91 secs   (2906 ticks @ 1000 us, 1 processor)
total alloc = 1,300,813,124 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)
```

The profiling results using `opEvery'` (point free version):

```
total time  =        3.24 secs   (3242 ticks @ 1000 us, 1 processor)
total alloc = 1,300,933,160 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)
```

However, I expected both versions to be equivalent (in all senses).

Comment: Yes, it would probably help if you posted full runnable code that demonstrates the problem. There are so many variations between compiler versions, code usage patterns, etc. that it's difficult to help with only a vague description.

Comment: One thing that comes to mind is that GHC might have an easier time inlining the first version of the code because applications are saturated.

Comment: Is `Stream` from a library, or did you implement it yourself? (If it is a library type, which library?)

Comment: @shachaf OK, I will try to make a little program reproducing this behavior. Hopefully, it'll be there here soon.

Comment: @dbaupp Stream is a type synonym for another type. I'm trying different data types to see which is the one that better suite my needs. Currently it's a [difference list](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/dlist/0.5/doc/html/Data-DList.html#t:DList).

Comment: I have added a simple test case.

Comment: I get more or less exactly the same runtime for `opEvery` and `opEvery'` with `-O2` (in both GHC 7.6.2 and 7.4.1). What version of GHC are you using? How are you running it exactly?

Comment: @shachaf Running with `pf.exe +RTS -p -RTS`. Compiled with GHC 7.4.2.

Comment: with ghc-7.4.2 and compiled with `-O2`, the core shows no difference between `opEvery` and `opEvery'`.  In fact, `Foo.opEvery = Foo.opEvery'`.  Perhaps the difference only appears when compiled for profiling?

Comment: And compiling with `ghc -O2 -prof -fprof-auto hi.hs`? (These details matter!) I see a difference when compiling and running that way, so it's probably some profiling quirk. Profiling can interfere with inlining and rewrite rules and such, so I wouldn't be too concerned with this (unless there's some good reason to care about profiling runtime?).

Comment: I get the same results again and again. I don't have a good reason to care about profiling runtime, it's just that profiling is the way I am using to measure the performance of my code.

Comment: @DanielDíaz: unfortunately Haskell code compiled for profiling is not entirely indicative of the performance of non-profiled code.  The divergence can be much larger than this.  At least for the list version, the difference is entirely due to constraints imposed by enabling profiling.

Comment: @shachaf of course the code will be different with those flags (I did check it).  My point is that the difference is imposed simply by building for profiling, whereas a non-profiled build uses *exactly the same* function.

Comment: @JohnL Well, that is good to know.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For the simple test case, both versions yield the same core when compiled with optimisations, but without profiling.

When compiling with profiling enabled (`-prof -fprof-auto`), the pointfull version gets inlined, resulting in the main part being

```
Rec {
Main.main_go [Occ=LoopBreaker]
  :: [GHC.Integer.Type.Integer] -> [GHC.Integer.Type.Integer]
[GblId, Arity=1, Str=DmdType S]
Main.main_go =
  \ (ds_asR :: [GHC.Integer.Type.Integer]) ->
    case ds_asR of _ {
      [] -> xs_r1L8;
      : y_asW ys_asX ->
        let {
          r_aeN [Dmd=Just S] :: [GHC.Integer.Type.Integer]
          [LclId, Str=DmdType]
          r_aeN = Main.main_go ys_asX } in
        scctick<opEvery.\>
        GHC.Base.map
          @ GHC.Integer.Type.Integer
          @ GHC.Integer.Type.Integer
          (GHC.Integer.Type.plusInteger y_asW)
          r_aeN
    }
end Rec }
```

(you get something better without profiling).

When compiling the pointfree version with profiling enabled, `opEvery'` is not inlined, and you get

```
Main.opEvery'
  :: forall a_aeW.
     (a_aeW -> a_aeW -> a_aeW) -> [a_aeW] -> [a_aeW] -> [a_aeW]
[GblId,
 Str=DmdType,
 Unf=Unf{Src=<vanilla>, TopLvl=True, Arity=0, Value=False,
         ConLike=False, WorkFree=False, Expandable=False,
         Guidance=IF_ARGS [] 80 60}]
Main.opEvery' =
  \ (@ a_c) ->
    tick<opEvery'>
    \ (x_ass :: a_c -> a_c -> a_c) ->
      scc<opEvery'>
      GHC.Base.foldr
        @ a_c
        @ [a_c]
        (\ (x1_XsN :: a_c) -> GHC.Base.map @ a_c @ a_c (x_ass x1_XsN))

Main.main4 :: [GHC.Integer.Type.Integer]
[GblId,
 Str=DmdType,
 Unf=Unf{Src=<vanilla>, TopLvl=True, Arity=0, Value=False,
         ConLike=False, WorkFree=False, Expandable=False,
         Guidance=IF_ARGS [] 40 0}]
Main.main4 =
  scc<main>
  Main.opEvery'
    @ GHC.Integer.Type.Integer
    GHC.Integer.Type.plusInteger
    Main.main7
    Main.main5
```

When you add an `{-# INLINABLE opEvery' #-}` pragma, it can be inlined even when compiling for profiling, giving

```
Rec {
Main.main_go [Occ=LoopBreaker]
  :: [GHC.Integer.Type.Integer] -> [GHC.Integer.Type.Integer]
[GblId, Arity=1, Str=DmdType S]
Main.main_go =
  \ (ds_asz :: [GHC.Integer.Type.Integer]) ->
    case ds_asz of _ {
      [] -> lvl_r1KU;
      : y_asE ys_asF ->
        GHC.Base.map
          @ GHC.Integer.Type.Integer
          @ GHC.Integer.Type.Integer
          (GHC.Integer.Type.plusInteger y_asE)
          (Main.main_go ys_asF)
    }
end Rec }
```

which is even a bit faster than the pragma-less pointfull version, since it doesn't need to tick the counters.

It is likely that a similar effect occurred for the `Stream` case.

The takeaway:

- Profiling inhibits optimisations. Code that is equivalent without profiling may not be with profiling support.
- Never measure performance using code that was compiled for profiling or without optimisations.
- Profiling can help you find out where the time is spent in your code [but, occasionally, enabling profiling can entirely alter the behaviour of the code; anything relying heavily on rewrite-rule optimisations and/or inlining is a candidate for that to happen], but it cannot tell you how fast your code is.

Comment: This is a complete answer. It took me some time to go thru the Core code though. Then the conclusion is that pointfree an pointful code both have the same performance, but profiling compilation makes the difference. So the message is: please profile responsibly.

Answer (score 2):

This is a big assumption on what I'm going to say, but I think the compiler has got not enough information to optimize your program. While not answering directly to your question but adding the `Eq a` constraint to both functions (as a test) I've got an improvement from the pointfree variant. See image attached (splits explanation)

```
Right -> TOP = everyOp initial, BOTTOM = everyOp' initial
Left  -> TOP = everyOp with Eq a constraint, BOTTOM = everyOp' Eq a constraint
```

[image]

EDIT: I'm using GHC 7.4.2

Comment: What the `Eq` instance has to do here? Why is it making a difference?

Comment: As I said, it's only based on assumptions; but giving a constraint on `a` (be it of any kind) the compiler would know that `a` is not for example of type `IO ()` and it could transform the execution of the operation with certain guarantees (order is not important).